# exp in SBCL is wrong?

Tags: lisp, sbcl

CL-USER> (exp 1)
2.7182817

Why? It should be 2.7182818 (rounded from 2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669...)

SBCL 1.0.29.11.debian

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a rounding error inherent in the IEEE single-float format.

```
CL-USER> (exp 1.0d0)
2.718281828459045d0
```

Answer (score 3):

Learn more about floating point arithmetic and its 'problems' in this classic paper (PDF):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://dlc.sun.com/pdf/800-7895/800-7895.pdf)

Comment: I think Oracle recently (since Jan 23 I guess) moved a bunch of stuff to a new CMS ... anyway here's another link I found when that one broke: http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~jkolesar/mait613/floating_point_math.pdf