# Why round is incorrect in CCL?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, floating-point-precision, ccl

I have learning Common Lisp for 2 months, I meet a puzzle, here is the code:

```
CL-USER> (round 33.6)
34
-0.40000153
```

anyone explain it? Thanks

Comment: Also see [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*, by David Goldberg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Also see [Mysterious problem with floating point in LISP - time axis generation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6225211/1281433), [exp in SBCL is wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4771346/1281433), [Floating Point Precision Error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20490115/1281433), [(Racket/Scheme) Subtraction yields result off by incredibly small margin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13693041/1281433), [Why in Common Lisp, when I run the function “acos” with an argument of 1, is the answer is wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17424545/1281433), …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. In CLisp, `round` rounds to the nearest integer (unless you specify a divisor). The nearest integer to `33.6` is `34` so that bit is right.

And since `round` returns both the quotient *and* remainder, it gives `34`, with a remainder of `-0.4`. That bit's *mostly* right so I suspect you're wondering why it's only *"mostly".*

The reason it's not *exactly* `-0.4` is almost certainly due to the limited precision of floating point numbers. The result of calculating the difference between a (seemingly exact) floating point number and an integer can be surprising:

```
CL-USER> (- 23.6 24) -0.39999962
```

You'd expect in a perfect world for that to return `-0.4` but it doesn't, for reasons mentioned above.

If you want to know *why* that's the case (i.e., how floating point works under the covers), you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635537/c-floating-point-precision/12635666#12635666) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448777/how-to-represent-0-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic-and-decimal/3448855#3448855) as examples.

Comment: `CL-USER> (- 23.6 24)
-0.39999962`

Comment: I want to konw the datials low-level

Comment: calculating between 2 floating number: CL-USER> (+ 25.2 2.2)
27.400002

Comment: @Hercules, I've updated the answer to point you to other questions asking about floating point foibles.

Comment: Thanks! though I did not make the low-level implemention of CCL clear, I got how float stores.

Comment: @HerculesShek you can use `disassemble` in LISP to really get down and dirty with what's happening with an arithmetic operation, but you'll find, at that level, it's not much different than any other language and you really are dealing with general floating point precision issues.